# cmd the screen cannot be set to number of lines and column specified

Tags: cmd

Every time I open my Command prompt it flashes the below message and then closes immediately.

> the screen cannot be set to number of lines and column specified

- What is the problem?
- How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you use mode command to specify the size of window?

Comment: No I havent done any such things but from last few months it keeps on flashing the same message as mentioned

Comment: add something like mode 600 in the beginning of the batch and try

Comment: I wasted my whole day fixing this, Thanks for your question & @amarmishra for the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this issue myself. After a lot of searching finally got it resolved.
Follow these steps to resolve.

**1.a)** Open Run (windows key + r) and enter "%appdata%" without quotes and press enter.

**1.b)** Go to the Microsoft folder and delete the SoundMixer folder contained within (This is the mining software).

**1.c)** Open Run and enter "regedit.exe" without quotes.

**1.d)** Find the registry entry mentioned as([HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]) and remove it. This entry attempts to run the miner whenever a CMD is started.

**2.a)** Go to the winlogon registry entry in the same regedit software ([HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon])

**2.b)** Check the sub-key named "shell" and change its value to "explorer.exe" without the quotes. (This means when you log onto windows it will no longer attempt to run the miner and instead start up normally.)

This worked for me.

[Answer Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/7jjey0/cmd_shows_the_screen_cannot_be_set_to_the_number/)